# Disable sticky navigation bar on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to disable sticky navigation bar on mobile(below 23cm).

My navigation bar is sticky already on all devices. Even in mobile devices(like iphone,ipad). It looks bad so I want to disable sticky nav bar only on mobile. Help me please:)

You can check my site. My site is [here](http://www.samgyoyu.com). Thank you.

Comment: Where is sticky navigation bar. I don't see

Comment: @PiyushMarvaniya Hi, Piyush:) Thank you for your comment. My navigation bar(=menu bar=top strip) is on very top of my site. You can see my small logo, four menus, and search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this isn't an option on your theme, you can add this CSS within a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   #masthead .top-strip { position:relative; }
}
```

You might need to add the "!important" after the "relative" if that doesn't work. And, of course, simply change the max-width to the max size of the screen where you DON'T want the nav bar to float.

Then you'll get some extra space in between the logo and the navigation bar (since we just put the navigation bar back into the flow of the page). To fix that, you'll need to find this in your CSS and put it within an @media query only for screens that are larger than the mobile:

```
@media (min-width: 601px) {
   #masthead #branding { margin: 90px auto 10px !important; }
}
```

If you want to test out sizes, I use http://www.responsinator.com/.